# How to get difference between two excel columns

Tags: excel

Column A contains active user's name, and column B contains all user's name. How can I get the difference between the two lists (inactive users)?

Comment: index match should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column C1 you can use:

```
=if(countif(A:A, B1)<1, "Inactive", "")
```

And copy that down for every name in column `B` and it will add the word "Inactive" on any records where the name in `B` is not found in column `A`.

You can then sort by Column C to group them all together. Or autofilter. Or pivot table.